# ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(10,11): error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, jquery-ui

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {NavabrComponent} from './navber/navbar.component';


const routes: Routes = [

{path: '' redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch:'full'},
{path: 'home', component:HomeComponent}


];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
 
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
   exports:[RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

some thing changing on my webpage and it run the server --> ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(10,11): error TS1005: ',' expected.it will be displayed
Every time run the project this error will be displayed.how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The comma is missing on this line

```js
{path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch:'full'},
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you everything you should know, consider looking into that a bit more, before asking a question here. In your case add a comma(,) between `path` and `redirectTo`.